# Android - How to disable WiFi channel scan programatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

In Android, is there a way to programatically disable the WiFi channel scan?  Looking at WiFiManager I did not see anything short of disabling WiFi, but I'd like to just disable the channel scans.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t disable Wifi channel scan because this is a default system behavior (on every ~30 seconds Android check wifi channels).

One thing you can do is force to connect in any Wifi channel, so Android will no longer try to scan another channel.

Answer (score 1):

Wifi cannot disabled programatically but you can always prompt the user to disable with an intent to the wifi settings.

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

Comment: The doubt is about disable wifi channel scan and not about disable wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

Wifi channel scan can't be disabled but in my case I unreigistered the receiver which solved my problem.